# Could not resolve placeholder | Spring Placeholder

Tags: spring

I am trying to use Spring `<context:property-placeholder>` in my application for first time and encountering some issues, I have tried many things as well already Google and have seems few posts over SO.

I am having a web application and need to pass some keys to underlying Class, was thinking of using place holder for same.Here is the structure of my application

```
Main
  -java
  -resources
  -webapp
```

I have a `project.properties` file which is inside `resource` folder, this is how I am trying

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/project.properties" />
<beans:bean id="reCaptcha" class="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl">
  <beans:property name="privateKey" value="${demo.recapatcha_private_key}"/>
   <beans:property name="publicKey" value="${demo.recapatcha_public_key}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

But I am getting following exception on server startup

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'reCaptcha' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'demo.recapatcha_private_key'
```

I have already tried placing project.properties file at various location which includes inside
`WEB-INF/classes` and few other location at `webapp` but with no success.not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as though you're using a Maven project structure. Placing your `project.properties` inside `src/main/resources` is normal practice for resource files - as Maven will automatically transfer these to the classpath of the final artifact - which will be `/WEB-INF/classes` inside your war.

However, you should modify the `location` attribute of your `<context:property-placeholder>` tag and remove the `resources` folder prefix. The `resources` folder itself is not transferred to `/WEB-INF/classes` when the war file is built - and so won't be part of the runtime classpath. Just the folder contents are transferred.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:project.properties" />
```

Comment: I have already tried what you have suggested with no success, infact my understanding was same as you outlined

Comment: Is the `<context:property-placeholder>` declaration and the placeholders themselves all defined in the `servlet-context.xml`?

Comment: Yes both of these are defined in same file with same sequence.

Comment: Are you seeing the problem when running in a standalone app server, or when running the app server in your IDE? If in your IDE, the IDE may mess with the runtime classpath and so may not be picking the file up.